# Stop span from going to new line with flex column parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to stop the span from going to a new line when the parent is `flex-direction: column`?

```css
.card-content-column {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-content-column__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #004a88;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-content-column">
  <!--title row-->
  <h2 class="card-content-column__title">Taken with natural breathing
    <span class="asterisk-weight-normal">*</span></h2>
  <!--content-->
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason to use `flexbox` inside `h2`? You could just remove it

Comment: good call, the reason for flex on the title is to line up titles by the baseline across numerous cards if that makes sense, hence the flex-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the h2's display property to **inline-block**. It will work.

```css
 .card-content-column {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .card-content-column__title {
        font-size: 24px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        color: #004a88;
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <body>
      <div class="card-content-column">
        <!--title row-->
        <h2 class="card-content-column__title">
          Taken with natural breathing
          <span class="asterisk-weight-normal">*</span>
        </h2>
        <!--content-->
      </div>

      <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [display:contents](https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/)

```css
.card-content-column {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-content-column__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #004a88;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.card-content-column__title .asterisk-weight-normal {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-content-column">
  <!--title row-->
  <h2 class="card-content-column__title">
    Taken with natural breathing
    <span class="asterisk-weight-normal">*</span>
    <span>extra column</span>
    <span>extra column</span>
  </h2>
  <!--content-->
</div>
```

Comment: `display: contents` currently has poor browser support. Not a good solution today. https://www.caniuse.com/#search=display%20content

Comment: I had initially tried display: contents but as comment above stated browser support is not good, specifically IE....but what else is new there ;) lol